# Redirect URI Mismatch Google OAuth or Database Access Denied

Tags: google-oauth, odoo, odoo-9, google-signin

I have got OAuth Client ID and Secret for Google API.

I have set the client id in Google OAuth provider record in Odoo.

I have my appropriate live domain. When I tried to login using Google, the google login screen appears. I enter appropriate google credentials, google logs me in and then google tries to redirect back to my odoo instance based on the redirect_uri key specified in the url. This is the point of time I am facing error of "redirect_uir_mismatch". If I open a new tab and go to google it shows me logged in.

I tried matching the **'redirect_uri'** registered with Google OAuth registration with the key **'redirect_uri'** in the url that is used for google login both are same.

I registered following redirect_uri: **`http://erp.mydomain.com/auth_oauth/signin`**. This same uri key is there in the url while login in to the google. But it throws error of 'redirect_uri_mismatch'

**Edit:**

I have deleted the client_id and secret and created new one and tried to test it and now I am having following error in my odoo instance:

> "You do not have access to this database or your invitation has expired. Please ask for an invitation and be sure to follow the link in your invitation email."

**Solution:**

You need to set the flag **`"auth_signup.allow_uninvited"`** to **`"True"`**

Comment: The error message tells you what the redirect uri is.  take that and put it in google developers console.

Comment: It is the same as what I have registered with google developer console. The additional it has is the query string containing 'response_type', client_id, scope. Also now I deleted that client_id and key and created new one and now it gives me the error of invitation expired or don't have access to database. I am not sure what is going on. Thank you for the reply !!

Comment: Interesting... where is the option for set flag *"auth_signup.allow_uninvited"* to *"True"* ?  I solved without touching any flag.

Comment: @Odedra It is there in "Security->Technical->Parameters->System Parameters". Does new user got created in your case?

Comment: Nope In my case, I don't do that. I think we must to send email for reset password invitation to User. Afterwards User will click on that link, it will redirect Odoo login. In login screen we have link name with Login with Google and nred to click on that and User login in Odoo System. Make sure login = user's email address.

Comment: Do you mean that I should first create a new user from administrator login and send the reset password link to the newly created user? Then when that user comes for rest pass. he should be redirect to google for login? I am trying to understand what you are saying and try to implement it.

Comment: @HardikPatadia, yes you are on right track with mine. ;-)

Comment: @Odedra When user comes to reset pass and go to google page for login than gets login into the odoo. Now how does he gets login into the system next time? Does he have to go to google every time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98320/discussion-between-odedra-and-hardik-patadia).

Comment: @Odedra I am there on the chat

Answer (score 1):

Yes I got the same error and resolve by the Configure Outgoing Email.

If outgoing mail server is not configure than it will give you error like as you face now.

For reset password, Odoo system will send email to User so System must have configure outgoing mail server.

Please configure outgoing mail server and test it again.

NOTE: Edit User data with login = his/her_email_id@gmail.com

Afterwards, Click on login with Google.com

It will work like a charm.

For more details: [Setting up Google Apps authentication with Odoo 8](https://odootricks.wordpress.com/2014/09/18/setting-up-google-apps-authentication-for-odoo/)

EDIT:

Yes you are correct @Hardik

We need to set the flag *"auth_signup.allow_uninvited"* to *"True"*

Comment: I will check it and get back here. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: I tried to configuring the email server, but still it shows the same error of "not have access to database or invitation has expired". The point is that this thing is working at my local side. So I am trying to understand where am I going wrong.

Comment: strange, it should be work, additional you may check out OAuth client id

Comment: I deleted the client_id and generated new one, but the result is same. Is there a way to do some debugging at server side, the way we do it during development? I was wondering if you have any guide for step by step registering client id, so that I can get to know, If I am missing any point.

Comment: I needed to make the "auth_signup.allow_uninvited" config parameter to "True". I think I forgot that. It is working now.